# show that the digit line topology is not compact.

Tags: general-topology

Digit line topology on $\Bbb Z$ is defined by the base

$$B(n)=\begin{cases}\{n\} & n \text{ is odd}\\ 
\{n-1,n,n+1\}& n \text{ is even}\\
\end{cases}, n \in \Bbb Z$$

Please give me the proof of the statement...Thank you

Comment: Thanks for edited.

Comment: Learn from it! MathJax is not that hard. You can find tutorials on the site.

Answer (score 2):

Does the open cover $B(n), n \in \Bbb Z$ have a finite subcover?

Comment: There is no finite subcover ...Yes?